# React Native ScrollView TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._subscribableSubscriptions.forEach')

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm building React Native app with Expo. It works fine on my Android device via Expo application. But I have the error after I've built apk via exp build:android command.

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this._subscribableSubscriptions.forEach')                                                  
This error is located at:
  in ScrollView
  in RCTView
  in r
  in Connect(r)
  in n
  in t
  in r
  in RCTView
  in RCTView
  in t
```

Problem is inside ScrollView. It is gone if I remove ScrollView. Here is my code snippet.

```
class Main extends Component {
state = {
    refreshing: false
};

renderCurrencies() {
    if (!Object.values(this.props.currencies).length) {
        return <View />;
    }

    return Object.values(this.props.currencies).map(item => {
        return (
            <CurrencyRow
                key={item.code}
                code={item.code}
                title={item.title}
            />
        );
    });
}

onRefresh = () => {
    Object.values(this.props.currencies).map(item => {
        this.props.sellBuyFetch(item.code);
    });
};

render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView
                refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                        onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
                    />
                }
            >
                {this.renderCurrencies()}
            </ScrollView>
        </View>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 40,
},
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bug is caused by `uglify-es 3.3.X` which is used when building a release version.

Add this block to your package.json:

`"resolutions": {
  "uglify-es": "3.2.2"
}`

I tried both publishing on Expo and building a standalone app and it's working like a charm now.

Comment: I saw this solution on the github, but somehow it didn't help me. Is there any cache I should clear or something like this?

Comment: check your project, node_modules\uglify-es\package.json, check its version. If it's still the 3.3.X version, you can delete the uglify-es folder and run `yarn` again, then in XDE, you can click Help->Clear XDE Cache

Answer (score 4):

Had same issue. 
Way to resolve this:

change

```
this._subscribableSubscriptions.forEach(
```

to

```
this._subscribableSubscriptions && this._subscribableSubscriptions.forEach(
```

in that file:

```
YOUR_PROJECT/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Subscribable.js
```

Comment: @kykapetak did you tried it with Expo? I think it builds APK with node modules from their side, so not help me.

Comment: @KyKaPeTuk's code change worked around the problem for me.  I'm not using CRNA or Expo (for these kind of reasons).

There's a thread on the react-native Github reponsitory: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17348

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, @kykapetuk and @chillypenguin. Looks like this React Native bug https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17348. In case with Expo we can't use the @kykapetuk workaround, cause APK builds on the Expo server. The current workaround for me - don't use Expo. Probably, the possible solution here to use another version react-native library.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code would be much simpler with a FlatList, however your problem might in this method: renderCurrencies()

Try to change it to this:

renderCurrencies = () => {

Maybe is not finding the props. Do you see any other issue in the log? If that does not help, debug the issue and find if (this) have that method inside it.

Note: I havewn't worked with Expo yet.

Comment: I've tried return just <View /> from renderCurrencies method, but no luck. So the problem isn't inside this method. Also tried FlatList (thanks for the tip), but have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

May be a bug in React Native 0.5.1.

I fixed it by evaluating variable this._subscribableSubscriptions on line 33 on react native file project/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/Subscribable.js

Changing this:

```
this._subscribableSubscriptions.forEach(
```

To this:

```
this._subscribableSubscriptions && this._subscribableSubscriptions.forEach(
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17348

Comment: Editing files in `node_modules` is never a good idea, as this will be overriden by the next update of a library

Comment: @NicoHaase react-native 0.55 merged this.